# insert data from multiple fields of similar information into fewer fields

Tags: ms-access-2007

I inherited a legacy ms access database.  I have one table with 30 fields of similar information.

JobID CityM1 StateM1 CityM2 StateM2 CityM3 StateM3 CityP1 StateP1 CityP2 StateP2.........

What I want to do is reduce the information to the following fields:

JobID.....Description (M or P).....City.....State

How do I use SQL to insert the data from all the related fields into the new table format.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably I would do the following:

If the old table is jobs_old(....) and new table is jobs_new(jobid, city, state, description), the primary key could be on jobid and city or jobid, city and state if city name is not unique in each state. You may have some other column to make the unique based on the normalization form.

Then I would execute a series of INSERT INTO jobs_new ... SELECT...FROM jobs_old to populate data into the new table by selecting data from appropriate columns from the old table. Examples:

```
INSERT INTO jobs_new(jobid, city, state, description) 
SELECT jobid, CityM1, StateM1, 'M' FROM jobs_old;

INSERT INTO jobs_new(jobid, city, state, description) 
SELECT jobid, CityM2, StateM2, 'M' FROM jobs_old;

...

INSERT INTO jobs_new(jobid, city, state, description) 
SELECT jobid, CityP1, StateP2, 'P' FROM jobs_old;

...
```

Note that I am hoping the statement syntax is accepted in MSACCESS! Otherwise, you have to use some other technique.

The table definition could be something like as following (used sqlcmd tool of MS SQL server):

```
1> CREATE TABLE jobs_new (jobid INT NOT NULL,
2> city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
3> description CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
4> PRIMARY KEY(jobid, city, state)
5> );
6> go
1>
```

Use appropriate data types for columns as per your requirements and change primary key columns as required.

Comment: I am able to move information to the jobs_new using INSERT INTO.  I am not able to do this with a series of INSERT INTOs into the same table though, so I'm left with the same problem of trying to put all of these fields into two fields.  How do I eventually combine this data into one table containg (JobID, city, state, description)?  Each job may have multiple entries.  I can get the data seperated with what you described but how do I incorporate into one table.  I guess I'm turnning all these fields into multiple rows under 3 field headings instead of 30.  Thanks.

Comment: I ended up making several smaller tables from the INSERT INTO syntax.  I left the JobID as text and had a seperate primary ID column.  I was then able to append one table to the other and then sort on the JobID to get data in the format I need.  There may be a better suggestion but it's working now....in a roundabout way which may be the only way when data is not normalized.

Comment: @user2734498, my solution was to put all data into single table jobs_new. If you define primary key on columns jobid, city and state for the table jobs_new, then you should be able to insert all rows into the same table. Note that the primary key should consist of all three columns. I do not see any reason why it does not work. If you can tell me the error you get, I may get some idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Added sample SQL statement to create required table in my answer above.

Comment: I built the table & used the insert. The issue I'm having is trying to use a series of inserts. If I use what you wrote as is then the error message is 'character found after end of sql statement'. If I remove all semicolons except the last one I get a syntax error in FROM clause. Something may be missing?

Comment: I have checked my statements in MS Access 2007 through "SQL View" option and they worked. You run one INSERT...SELECT statement at a time. You will be able to add all rows int just one table.

Comment: Ok. Tried the statements one at a time into the same table and it worked. Thanks for your time and effort. I finally get it!